# Bad setting of LVM volumes - I cant extend partition

Tags: centos, lvm, partition

I have little mistake on configuration with LVM partions. It is virtual machine in esxi.

- I need extend LogVol01 in vg_vmm02.
- /dev/sdc was extended in hypervisor to 10GB (from 5).
- Problem is that I forgot create sdb1 or sdc1 via fdisk before, so LVM partion is created directly on /dev/sdc
- In fdisk /dev/sdc now I cant add new partition, because fdisk want primary rewrite parts from start of sdc
- in vgdisplay I can't see any free space
- via Partition Magic live cd with gui I can't expand lvm too.

What is the best way fix it and use 5GB of free space from sdc? Thanks

```
lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                           11:0    1  624M  0 rom
sda                            8:0    0   40G  0 disk
├─sda1                         8:1    0  200M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                         8:2    0 37.9G  0 part
│ ├─vg_vmm02-LogVol00 (dm-0) 253:0    0 11.8G  0 lvm  /
│ └─vg_vmm02-LogVol01 (dm-1) 253:1    0 41.1G  0 lvm  /www
└─sda3                         8:3    0    2G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb                            8:16   0   10G  0 disk
├─vg_vmm02-LogVol00 (dm-0)   253:0    0 11.8G  0 lvm  /
└─vg_vmm02-LogVol01 (dm-1)   253:1    0 41.1G  0 lvm  /www
sdc                            8:32   0   10G  0 disk
└─vg_vmm02-LogVol01 (dm-1)   253:1    0 41.1G  0 lvm  /www


vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_vmm02
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        3
  Metadata Sequence No  11
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                3
  Act PV                3
  VG Size               52.84 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              13527
  Alloc PE / Size       13527 / 52.84 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               LmLmD1-ucp9-Pj3G-Po7W-s9bq-GMQ6-7jFErM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `pvresize /dev/sdc`, then a `vgs` will show free space that you can assign to the specific logical volume.

As always, take a snapshot/backup first.